# mysqlコネクションプールにおけるqueryの挙動の違いについて

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = {
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database : "test",
    connectionLimit : 10
}
const pool = mysql.createPool(config);
let strQuery = 'SELECT * FROM `test`';
//①getConnectionからqueryを実行
pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
    if(err) throw err;
    conn.query(strQuery,function(error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(results);
        conn.release();
    });
});
//②直接queryを実行
pool.query(strQuery,function(error,results,fields){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
});
```

この二つのクエリの挙動は内部ではどう違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 英語版のStackOverflowに同じ質問がされています。こちらを参照下さい。 [Difference between using getConnection() and using pool directly in node.js with node-mysql module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783571/difference-between-using-getconnection-and-using-pool-directly-in-node-js-with)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool

> ... the pool.query method is a short-hand for the pool.getConnection -> connection.query -> connection.release() ...

`pool.query()`は`pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> pool.release()`の一連の流れを処理を実行するショートハンドなので、内部でコネクションプールの取得、クエリング、コネクションのクローズを一気にやっています。ひとつのコネクションに対して複数のクエリを発行する場合には、`pool.query()`を使わずに、`pool.getConnection()`でコネクションを握ってからコールバック内で複数のクエリ発行を処理するのが良いかと思います。